# How to shrinkwrap maintaining plane ratio?

Tags: shrinkwrap

Right now I'm projecting subdivided plane onto "wavy" mesh by using shrinkwrap modifier. Thing is that shrinkwrap modifier is not maintaining plane ratio. Is there any other way to project plane onto deformed surface? (while maintaining distances between vertices of that plane)

Here is current result:
[image]

Comment: You may be interested in the remesh modifier or the standalone program "Meshlab".

Comment: @Leander how this comment is useful here?

Comment: The proposed tools project quadbased geometry onto uneven existing geomtry. Isn't that someting that you want?

Comment: You can also try the cloth simulation.